# The new actionbar icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

With the new material design in Android, Google uses new actionbar icons and new floating action button icons in their apps. Can someone link me where I can find them?

Comment: Android resources are found on your hard disk. On my installation, they are found here: `C:\Program Files\Adt-Bundle\sdk\platforms\android-xy\data\res` - xy is 21, in your case.

Comment: Not sure whether to say this is off-topic or not... also, @DerGolem, that's definitely just a Windows specific path.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Yes. I specified **On my installation...**. On yours, it might be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no implementation of a FAB provided by the platform, you have to implement that yourself. There are a number of excellent libraries for them that can be found with a quick Google.

As for the new iconography, check out Google's repo here: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons